# About MB-lab addon. How can I fix the problem with red eyelids in characters?

Tags: shaders, light, manuel-bastioni-lab

When there is a lot of light on the stage, the red eyelids are almost invisible. But when you want to make a dark environment, the eyelids glow red like lanterns.  How can I fix this? I'm using mb-lab 1.7.7.
UPD: I found out that the red glowing is not only on the eyelids, but also on any other thin parts of the body that are in the dark. They have this same glow along the contour.

You can see this red eyelids in the picture:

[image]

Here is a .blend file:

[image]

I found nothing on the web. Just one person asked a similar question on another forum, but nobody answered. And there is no forum just for mb-lab users, so I'm asking here.

Comment: A lot of people who can help you but do not use MBL are not going to be able to just guess what's wrong just by looking at the picture... No point in limiting your chances of getting good answers like that, is there?.. It would be better to post a .blend file showing the issue in your question. You can [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/175150/edit) and add a blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys, added a .blend file.

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing SSS (Sunsurface scattering). It can be found under Skin Editor/ skin_sss
[image]